# Plotting a timing diagram using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I want to implement a timing diagram of a simple AND circuit which takes A and B as input and gives C as Output along with any clock delay. But I have not encountered any code here or at any at any other site which helped me or gave any clues. Have no clue as to how to approach this problem.
New at python and matplotlib library. Will appreciate any kind of help or suggestion.
Thanks!

Comment: I dont think matplotlib was the good library for drawing eltronic schema

Comment: What should I go with then? Any suggestion will help.

Answer (score 2):

Use the function plt.step()

View the doc : https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def my_lines(ax, pos, *args, **kwargs):
    if ax == 'x':
        for p in pos:
            plt.axvline(p, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        for p in pos:
            plt.axhline(p, *args, **kwargs)

bits = [0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0]
data = np.repeat(bits, 2)
clock = 1 - np.arange(len(data)) % 2
manchester = 1 - np.logical_xor(clock, data)
t = 0.5 * np.arange(len(data))


my_lines('x', range(13), color='.5', linewidth=2)
my_lines('y', [0.5, 2, 4], color='.5', linewidth=2)
plt.step(t, clock + 4, 'r', linewidth = 2, where='post')
plt.step(t, data + 2, 'r', linewidth = 2, where='post')
plt.step(t, manchester, 'r', linewidth = 2, where='post')
plt.ylim([-1,6])

for tbit, bit in enumerate(bits):
    plt.text(tbit + 0.5, 1.5, str(bit))

plt.gca().axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a couple of links that would help you.

1. Wavedrom Python Package
   https://pypi.org/project/wavedrom/
2. Drawtime - Editor and renderer for timing diagrams (Found while doing a random search) 
    Source :
    https://github.com/max99x/drawtime

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll check that out. Thanks!